# Must restart Adventurer 3 before it will heat up

Tags: change-filament, heat

I had a pretty big problem with clogs, at both the nozzle and the other end too.  I fixed those and installed a new nozzle.  Now I can print.

But when I go to change the filament, it won't heat up and shows 35/0 degrees.  I have to shut down the printer completely before I can get it to heat up.  So I can no longer change colors mid-print.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "the other end"? Are you talking about the extruder end? Also, what is "35/0 degrees"? Help us, help you.

Comment: It was clogged near the extruder, and also near the wheels where you start the filament feed.  The nozzle is still clogged, which is why I replaced it.  The other clogs are cleared, since the new nozzle works and it does print.  But when it tries to heat, either by choosing "Preheat" or Filament then Change, the display shows the temperature as 35 out of a target 0 degrees, and stays stuck like that. It should show 35 out of a target 240 degrees and the 35 should slowly increase til it gets to 240.